# Crash on iPhone 6. not able to get the Reason

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, crash, crash-reports

I am developing an app that tracks User. My Application is crashing we i put app in background after that crash loop happen. App crashes every time I launch it. I have symbolicated crash logs but not able to find the exact cause for crash. The symbolicated crash log is given below. Can any one tell me the reason?

```
Incident Identifier: 7C3297BB-50EA-4C2A-9F84-FA4A56BC5C3C
CrashReporter Key:   1a78eeb10921ee0a03ccb84ec0c49a835ee54426
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:             myapp_SIT [840]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Applicatio/893B00C1-431B-4CA7-9867-FE9F3B49D5E3/myapp_SIT.app/myapp_SIT
Identifier:          com.mycompany.myapp.sit
Version:             2.0.3 (2.0.3)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-04-18 13:23:18.039 +0200
Launch Time:         2015-04-18 13:23:17.269 +0200
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F70)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000c0000010
Triggered by Thread:  8

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33656474 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33656269 mach_msg + 37
2   CoreFoundation                  0x24a6556f __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 143
3   CoreFoundation                  0x24a63b15 __CFRunLoopRun + 1013
4   CoreFoundation                  0x249b01fd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 473
5   CoreFoundation                  0x249b000f CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
6   GraphicsServices                0x2c2491fd GSEventRunModal + 133
7   UIKit                           0x28154a55 UIApplicationMain + 1437
8   myapp_SIT                   0x001c1400 main (AppDelegate.swift:0)
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x3359faad start + 1

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33656224 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3358b0ed _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 277
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3357fd37 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 35

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3366a9c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x336e5e39 _pthread_wqthread + 789
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x336e5b10 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3366a9c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x336e5e39 _pthread_wqthread + 789
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x336e5b10 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3366a9c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x336e5e39 _pthread_wqthread + 789
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x336e5b10 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3366a9c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x336e5e39 _pthread_wqthread + 789
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x336e5b10 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3366a9c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x336e5e39 _pthread_wqthread + 789
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x336e5b10 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3366a9c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x336e5e39 _pthread_wqthread + 789
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x336e5b10 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos
Thread 8 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3302d709 objc_release + 9
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3302e1a5 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 401
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x335884cd _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1721
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x335893bf _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x336e5dbf _pthread_wqthread + 667
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x336e5b10 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33656474 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33656269 mach_msg + 37
2   CoreFoundation                  0x24a6556f __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 143
3   CoreFoundation                  0x24a63b15 __CFRunLoopRun + 1013
4   CoreFoundation                  0x249b01fd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 473
5   CoreFoundation                  0x249b000f CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
6   CFNetwork                       0x2454e7eb +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 483
7   Foundation                      0x257de3b7 __NSThread__main__ + 1115
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x336e7e21 _pthread_body + 137
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x336e7d93 _pthread_start + 115
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x336e5b1c thread_start + 4

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3366a9c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x336e5e39 _pthread_wqthread + 789
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x336e5b10 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 11 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3366a080 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x24a69d61 __CFSocketManager + 533
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x336e7e21 _pthread_body + 137
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x336e7d93 _pthread_start + 115
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x336e5b1c thread_start + 4

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33656474 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33656269 mach_msg + 37
2   myapp_SIT                   0x002be18f exception_server_thread + 219
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x336e7e21 _pthread_body + 137
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x336e7d93 _pthread_start + 115
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x336e5b1c thread_start + 4

Thread 8 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x175f6720    r1: 0xc0000000      r2: 0x032c05fc      r3: 0x00000fff
    r4: 0x032c0000    r5: 0x032ba0a4      r6: 0x032c0000      r7: 0x032b9f7c
    r8: 0x032c0028    r9: 0x175ae000     r10: 0xa3a3a3a3     r11: 0x35cad074
    ip: 0x35cba124    sp: 0x032b9d58      lr: 0x3302e1a9      pc: 0x3302d708
  cpsr: 0x20000030
```

Comment: Symbolicated crash logs look different.

Comment: for symbolication i am using this command   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash  -v myapp.crash 2> symbolicate.log

Comment: same here on 6s,Still can't figure it why.

Answer (score 0):

**EXC_BAD_ACCESS** generally means that you are sending a **Obj-C** message to an invalid memory address. Usually this happens because an object that you are using has been deallocated, while you weren't expecting it to be *(here, probably HTTPMessage)*.

```
Thread 4 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
r0: 0x14e4f500    r1: 0xe0000000      r2: 0x00aec5fc      r3: 0x00000fff
r4: 0x00aec000    r5: 0x00e850a4      r6: 0x00aec000      r7: 0x00e84f7c
r8: 0x00aec028    r9: 0x14e47000     r10: 0xa3a3a3a3     r11: 0x35cad074
ip: 0x35cba124    sp: 0x00e84d58      lr: 0x3302e1a9      pc: 0x3302d708
cpsr: 0x20000030
```

> You can use **NSZombieEnabled** to get more information.

steps to simple for it:

## product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme ***(cmd + <)*** -> Check on Enable Zombie

Hope you will get something more about what you want

Comment: I am  getting this crash on only  iPhone 6. On other divices i am not geting this crash. this crash is random. not reproducing every time.

Comment: Not sure, but It might possible if your network is too slow and before your response is come you are redirected. so your response handler will not get by delegate...